# python search for a string in json

Tags: python, json, string

**Json** *table_data*

```
[
  {
    "country": "country one",
    "city": "city one",
    "Start Time": "21th December 2019 09:00 AM",
    "End time": "22th December 2019 03:00 PM"
  },
  {
   "country": "country two",
    "city": "city two",
    "Start Time": "23th December 2019 09:00 AM",
    "End time": "23th December 2019 03:00 PM"
  },
  {
 "country": "country three",
    "city": "city three",
    "Start Time": "24th December 2019 09:00 AM",
    "End time": "24th December 2019 03:00 PM"
  } 
]
```

so what i want to do is  look for a country and once i find the country u want to print the related data to it
i have done this so far

```
for dt in table_data:# this is not correct i think
    if("country one" == dt):
        print()
```

i am not sure how to approach this in python 
any assistance would be appreciated

Comment: I suggest that you read a tutorial on Python. Specifically, you need to learn about dictionaries and how to use them.

Comment: `if dt['country'] == "country one":`

Comment: @Code-Apprentice This is Python, not JS.

Comment: @Barmar Oops. Thanks for the catch. I think I saw the JSON tag and jumped to JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import json

data = json.loads("""
[
  {
    "country": "country one",
    "city": "city one",
    "Start Time": "21th December 2019 09:00 AM",
    "End time": "22th December 2019 03:00 PM"
  },
  {
   "country": "country two",
    "city": "city two",
    "Start Time": "23th December 2019 09:00 AM",
    "End time": "23th December 2019 03:00 PM"
  },
  {
 "country": "country three",
    "city": "city three",
    "Start Time": "24th December 2019 09:00 AM",
    "End time": "24th December 2019 03:00 PM"
  } 
]
""")

for this_country in data:
    if this_country['country'] == 'country two':
        print("\n".join([": ".join(k) for k in this_country.items()]))
```

Output:

```
country: country two
city: city two
Start Time: 23th December 2019 09:00 AM
End time: 23th December 2019 03:00 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
for data in table_data:
    if data['country'] == 'country one':
        print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start with something simpler. Let's say you have a `country` object:

```
country = {
    "country": "country one",
    "city": "city one",
    "Start Time": "21th December 2019 09:00 AM",
    "End time": "22th December 2019 03:00 PM"
  }
```

Now we want a function to print this object:

```
def print_country(c):
    pass
```

The first step is to figure out how to fill in the details of this function.